# Is there a flush method in the xlsxwriter module? [Python 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, io, xlsxwriter

So I am writing a program which writes data into an opened excel file. 
The issue is that I need to run an infinite loop and the program is closed when it is killed.

The file isn't even created when I do this. workbook.close() is outside the infinite while loop.

Is there a flush method within xlsxwriter so that I can save the data?

Comment: The xlsx format is rather involved, and xlswriter has is no `flush()`, and `save()` finalizes everything.   If you are continually adding rows, I would suggest saving the data as a csv instead of xlsx.  Then convert to xlsx later if needed.  Also 'openpyxl' seems able to do intermediate saves.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get around the problem by invoking the workbook.save() inside the loop. I have this long running program that keeps appending lines to the excel file and once the save method is invoked inside the loop, I can see new lines getting added as the program progresses.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a flush method in the xlsxwriter module

No. You can only `close()`/save a file once with XlsxWriter.